# NGINX reverse proxy to Apache docker container 404

Tags: docker, nginx, mediawiki

I'm trying to host several websites on my droplet. I'm to do that, I'm using NGINX (not container) as reverse proxy to Dockerized apps. One such app I'm using is the dockerized [Mediawiki](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki/) set to run on 0.0.0.0:8081.

Mediawiki container is based on `php7.2-apache`.

Nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    index index.php;

    server_name my.website.com;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I run the application on port 8081, as can be seen by through `docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER          IMAGE          PORTS
e40c9815d6cc       mediawiki      0.0.0.0:8081 -> 80/tcp
```

I can access my.website.com, but it shows the default Apache Ubuntu default page. Accessing other pages and resources (index.php, /folder/index.php, images/pic.jpg) returns 404.

Testing the container with similar setup on my machine local works. I think there maybe something up I didn't get with the NGINX config.

Help?

Comment: Which path your application is located? You have to set Document root and redirect rules also

Comment: Do you need Document root and redirect rules for proxy_pass?

Comment: No the apache config documentroot